# Select all items and count in related table by criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables Match and Reaction as following:

```
REACTION
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| user_id  | game_id  | item_id  | reaction |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |    1     |     1    |     1    |
|        1 |    1     |     2    |     1    |
|        2 |    1     |     1    |     1    |
|        2 |    1     |     2    |     0    |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

```
MATCH:
+----------+----------+
| game_id  | item_id  |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |    1     |
|        1 |    2     |
+----------+----------+
```

Now I want (if possible without subqueries) to select ALL item_ids from MATCH table AND count of rows where field reaction in table Reaction is equal to 1 for user with id = 2. For example, for defined tables I want to get following results:

```
+----------+----------+
|  item_id | count    |
+----------+----------+
|     1    |    1     |
|     2    |    0     |
+----------+----------+
```

I've tried something like

```
SELECT match.item_id, COUNT(reaction.user_id) as c
FROM match 
LEFT JOIN reaction ON reaction.item_id = match.item_id 
WHERE reaction.reaction = 1 AND match.game_id = 2
GROUP BY match.item_id
HAVING c > 0
```

but it didn't work as expected. I cannot get count for particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close.  I think you just need to move conditions on the second table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT m.item_id, COUNT(r.user_id) as c
FROM match m LEFT JOIN
     reaction r
     ON r.item_id = m.item_id AND
        r.reaction = 1 AND
        r.user_id = 2
WHERE m.game_id = 2
GROUP BY m.item_id;
```

I'm not sure what the `HAVING` clause is for, because you seem to want counts of `0`.

Note that this also introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: this seems to be working! I have just added one extra condition for joining: AND r.user_id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT match.item_id, COUNT(reaction.user_id) as c
FROM match JOIN reaction ON (reaction.item_id = match.item_id and reaction.reaction = 1 AND match.game_id = 2)
GROUP BY match.item_id
HAVING COUNT(reaction.user_id)
```

I think you need to filter 'before' join -> so use the 'on' clause.
Filters in `where` are applied **after** the join is made while filter applied on `on` clause are applied **before** the join is made

Comment: But again I have no idea how to include user_id = 2 in the criteria. I need to get count of reactions = 1 made by user 2 for example.

Comment: Put it into the where

Answer (score 0):

You have not  game_id = 2  so this should return no value
and you should not  use left  joined table columns in where condition otherwise these wprk as inner join  ... in these cases you shou move the related  condition in ON clause

```
SELECT match.item_id, COUNT(reaction.user_id) as c
FROM match 
LEFT JOIN reaction ON reaction.item_id = match.item_id  
    AND reaction.reaction = 1 
WHERE  match.game_id = 2
GROUP BY match.item_id
HAVING c > 0
```

but try also

```
SELECT match.item_id, COUNT(reaction.user_id) as c
FROM match 
LEFT JOIN reaction ON reaction.item_id = match.item_id  
    AND reaction.reaction = 1 

GROUP BY match.item_id
```

Comment: But again I have no idea how to include user_id = 2 in the criteria.

Comment: You have not user id  related  to the expcted  result ... so update  . your question and add  a clear sample and a coherent expected  result  ..